# Swiper slider does not load multiple views for slider layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using swiper slider from [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper)

I am trying to imitate demo-no-210 from that repository.

My code is as shown below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

    <style>
        .swiper-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .swiper-slide {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: #fff;
            /* Center slide text vertically */
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            /* width: 50px; */
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
    <title>xyz</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
        <script>
            var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                slidesPerGroup: 4,
                loop: true,
                loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,
                pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                    clickable: true,
                },
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                },
            });
        </script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

home.html

```
<div>
 <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But somehow, I could only slider image 1 and left-right arrows also do not work. 
The effect that I get is as shown below:
[image]

But I want to have multiple sliders as shown here [image]

Is there anything I  am missing here?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Developer Console?

Comment: There is no error in the Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your JavaScript down below you your html. Code below works okay but breaks the same as yours when I move the html below the JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

        <style>
            .swiper-container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .swiper-slide {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 18px;
                background: #fff;
                /* Center slide text vertically */
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                /* width: 50px; */
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -ms-flex-pack: center;
                -webkit-justify-content: center;
                justify-content: center;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                -webkit-align-items: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
        </style>
        <title>xyz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>


        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
        <script>
            var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                slidesPerGroup: 4,
                loop: true,
                loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,
                pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                    clickable: true,
                },
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                },
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works fine when I move it to index.html. But it does not work when I keep it in home.html. (Here, I want to integrate it in angular.js)

Comment: Try moving the slider initialization script below the angular script tag. I think the Slider isn't working because the html doesn't exist yet because angular doesn't generate it until we get to the very bottom of the page.

Comment: I tried that also, but unfortunately it did not work out.

Comment: @MrugeshThaker Two more suggestions for you so. 1. What if you wrap your initialization code in $(document).ready(). 2. Using jQuery's .noConfict(); See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/